# Does P^NP=NP imply NP=coNP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, p-vs-np, polynomial-hierarchy

If you have it, the proof would be appreciated.

Note: P^NP means P with NP oracle

Comment: This is an elementary result, which fits into the more general context of the polynomial hierarchy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy. I'd recommend asking follow up questions on cs.stackexchange.com if you have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it implies. $P^{NP}$ is the set of languages that are Turing reducible to $NP$ (for example, to $SAT$, or any other $NP$-complete problem). If we take a Boolean formula $F$, then $F\in UNSAT$ holds (meaning that $F$ is not satisfiable), if and only if $\overline{F}$ (the negation of $F$) is satisfiable. Since $UNSAT$ is co-$NP$-complete, and the reduction 
$F\mapsto\overline F$ is a Turing reduction, therefore, we get $UNSAT\in P^{NP}$,
implying co-$NP\subseteq P^{NP}$. If, by assumption, $P^{NP}=NP$, then we get 
co-$NP\subseteq NP$, which already implies  co-$NP= NP$.

I think, a reason for defining $NP$ via polynomial time many-one reductions, rather than Turing reductions is exactly that the latter would not allow the $NP$ vs co-$NP$ distinction.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.